# Use same onPress handle with multiple TouchableOpacity

Tags: javascript, react-native, gridview

I am using a GridView to show multiple products and on click i want to go to details screen , however I am unable to find a way to identify which product grid view cell was selected / tapped by user , I think sending some parameter to handle method should do the trick.

```js
return (

            <GridView
                itemDimension={130}
                items={this.state.dataSource}
                style={styles.gridView}
                renderItem={item => (
                    <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={ this.onPressStone } style={styles.itemContainer}>
                            <Image source = {{uri:item.url}} style={styles.imageView} />
                            <Text style={styles.itemName}>{item.name}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                )}
            />
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send parameters to your function like you said.

**Example**

```
onPress={ () => this.onPressStone(item.id) }
```

Comment: how will be the declaration of onPressStone then ?

Comment: ok got it but this fat arrow function makes me go made at a times and this is one such case , don't understand what it does exactly in this case does it returns a pointer to this function ?

Comment: @vishaldharankar basically you create a second function that runs `this.onPressStone` inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass to the method onPressStone the item and depending the item you could do that print what you want. And if you want to know who was pressed you just have to make a log with the name of the item or take the index for example

```
return (

        <GridView
            itemDimension={130}
            items={this.state.dataSource}
            style={styles.gridView}
            renderItem={(item, index) => {
             //to know who was pressed:
             console.log('pressedItemName-->', item.name);
             //to know index pressed:
             console.log('pressedItemName-->', item);
              return (
                <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={ ()=> {this.onPressStone(item)} } style={styles.itemContainer}>
                        <Image source = {{uri:item.url}} style={styles.imageView} />
                        <Text style={styles.itemName}>{item.name}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            )}
        />
```

);

Comment: this is not correct since `this.onPressStone(item)` will fire when the component renders and not on press.

Comment: ops its true,  i forgot put inside ()=>{}